# GWT - Trouble with History first token

Tags: gwt, history, gwt-history

I have this problem : when i call the Content class (the one who decide which page to view, due to the #param) I do somethings like this :

```
History.addValueChangeHandler(this);
if(!History.getToken().isEmpty()){
    changePage(History.getToken());
} else {
    History.newItem("homepage");
}
```

So, now, if i look at browser's navigation bar, i see `http://localhost:8084/GWT/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#homepage`. And that's right. Unfortunatly, If i press `Back` on my browser, i see that it load the previous address, such as `http://localhost:8084/GWT/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

I have a sort of "fake" page at the beginning.

1 - How can I fix it? And start the application with a default token, or remove it in the history. Or just call the `onValueChange` method when there is empty token, and after decide the workflow with a sort of switch/if-else.

2 - As related question, when i call `History.addValueChangeHandler(this);` in the costructor class, netbeans say "Leaking this in constructor". What it means?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, home url in form of "proto://hostname#homepage" is ugly :)

`1.` Just a suggestion:

```
String token = History.getToken();
String page = token.isEmpty() ? "homepage" : token;
changePage(page);
```

`2.` Does Your EntryPoint implement `ValueChangeHandler<String>`?

Comment: thanks for the answer. Uhm, not really. I Implements that interface where my content (flow panel) could change. Is is wrong?

Comment: There is one more thing, that You should take into account: internet explorer does not handle history state properly without special iframe, which should be incorporated to Your index.html <body> section. It should look like <html><head>...<body><iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>...

Comment: Secondly, You should wrap [1] into method and call it on page load too (as others have already pointed)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you forgot to add  `History.fireCurrentHistoryState();` to end of `onModuleLoad()` method?

Comment: In fact i don't have call History directly on onModuleLoad(), but on another Class, "added" when the onModuleLoad start. Is it a problem? And yes, i never call that method...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a history token and fire the history change event with current token.
Heres how you could do it:

```
/ If the application starts with no history token, redirect to a new
// 'homepage' state.
String initToken = History.getToken();
if (initToken.length() == 0) {
  History.newItem("homepage");
}

// Add widgets etc


// Add history listener
History.addHistoryListener(yourHistoryHandler);

// Fire the initial history state.
History.fireCurrentHistoryState();
```

Comment: What the need to call fireCurrenthistoryState() ?? Is it only needed at first time as after calling first time, from any other class if you call History.newItem("test") it will work. no need to call fireCurrenthistoryState() again why ??

Comment: Consider a situation wherein the user directly tries to open a URL in your web app , say- http://your-app/#settings.

In this scenario, the initial value of history token would be #settings. Needless to say that when you attach a HistoryListener later on in code, it would not capture the initial history token since a history change was never fired.

Hence, it is always better to fire the current history state of your app to ensure that your history change listeners have received it.

Comment: hey just got it....if your history handler in not loaded first then..u need to fine current history token...once history handler loaded then one need to fire current history toekn